# How to display the username entered from the user on the next page with php

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

I have on my home page two input boxes one for the user name and one for the password. I have a php file which will check my database to check these credentials and either allow or deny acces. When the user gains access i want to display on my screen, Logged in as:...."the user name entered on home page to login"....

here is my code which checks my database to allow or deny access.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="********"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db?K1012904"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="AdminUser"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:loginsuccess.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
}
?>
```

Here is where the user will enter credentials

```
 <form name="form1" class="navbar-form pull-right" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
          <input name="myusername"  type="text"  id="myusername" placeholder="Email">
          <input name="mypassword" id="mypassword" class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Password">
          <button type="submit" name="submit"class="btn">Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

and here is where i am trying to display the username

```
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
    Logged in as: <?php echo $myusername ?> </p>
```

my problem is that i cant seem to display the username entered by the user, any ideas on how i can get this working?

Comment: `$_SESSION['myusername']`

Answer (score 1):

You have usernames stored in the database, just store a user_id in the session:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = // whatever the logged in user's id ends up being.
```

Then, on any subsequent pages, pull that user_id, and run a select on the database to find other client information.  The database should be your canonical source of user data, not the $_SESSION, apart from an "is-logged-in" database id identifier, otherwise it leads to problems down the line.

As an aside, you want to be looking into stored procedures and [PDO bound queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to secure your life, because mysql_query is old-school & deprecated.  Similarly, stripslashes() is a bad sign.  Oh, and you're using plaintext passwords.

So, overall, ask yourself whether you really want to write your own login security system and revisit all the standard problems that everyone has with security when they do so?  Instead, look into an open source authentication project's solution to this *repeatedly* solved problem.  Here is a search for [php authentication on github with 867 results](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=php+authentication) to start with instead of rolling your own, which is not recommended for the security-inexperienced.

See also:
http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=1 Pear Auth classes
https://github.com/Kausheel/Authentication  Github Auth Repository to crib from

Answer (score 1):

`session_register` is deprecated in php 5.3 and removed from php 5.4 so your session code might not work at all.

You should put `session_start();` at the top of every page that uses sessions and assign your variables like:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
```

You can then access it like:

```
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
```

on pages where a session was started.

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
session_start();
```

before

```
session_register();
```

Answer (score 0):

A few of the methods you are using are deprecated but should still work.

You're setting a session variable called myusername which stores the users username. So once on the page you want to echo the current username to, you would want to echo the variable $_SESSION['myusername'].

For example

```
<p class="navbar-text pull-right">
Logged in as: <?php echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?> </p>
```

I could be wrong but I'm sure this will be ok.

Comment: I have added this into my code, however, i am still not seeing what the user has entered?

Comment: I think that the use of the session_register function has actually been deleted. In your code, change:

    `session_register("myusername");  
    session_register("mypassword");` 

to:

    `$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];
    $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $_POST['mypassword'];`

Then give it a try.

Also make sure you have added session_start() at the very top of your page, just after your opening php tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could store data in a session var just when you logged in with

```
session_start();
...
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name; $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

but don't forget to destroy the session var on logout with **session_destroy()**